# Angular class names based on item values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to know how can I add dynamic class name to my `<div>` based on item values in angular?

## Example

item status is `open` add class `bg-success` Or item status is `pending` add class `bg-warning`

## code

`Component`

```
const badgeColors = {
  'Open': 'bg-primary',
  'pending': 'bg-warning',
  'Finished': 'bg-success',
  'Expired': 'bg-danger'
}
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let item of listOfData" :key="item.id">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="otherClasses bg-warning"></div> <-- I need to change this static `bg-warning` to dynamic `badgeColors`
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! I had an answer for the question you just [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65016412/angular-separate-data-by-status), in case you wanted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply call ngClass on your div like

```
[ngClass]="displayDynamicColour(item.status)"
```

and in your ts

```
const badgeColors = {
  'Open': 'bg-primary',
  'pending': 'bg-warning',
  'Finished': 'bg-success',
  'Expired': 'bg-danger'
}

displayDynamicColour(item){
return this.badgeColors[item];
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it should be `[ngClass]="displayDynamicColour(item.status)"` please wait 9min so i can be allowed to accept your answer :)

Comment: yep, I have edited my answer, happy coding brother..

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngClass directive. For example:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'bg-success': (status === open), 'bg-warning': (status === pending)}"> </div>
```